# Why addresses of instructions from GDB and Objdump are the same?

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, reverse-engineering, objdump

I am diving into Reverse Engineering, which is really fun.

I have a question however: why the addresses of instructions I get from **GDB** and **Objdump** are the same?

**Shouldn't the binary be loaded at a different address every time?**

Thank you.
Julien

Comment: Traditionally, binaries are loaded to fixed addresses on Unix.  You can have binaries whose load address is only determined at runtime, this is called PIE (position independent executable).

Comment: ... and every process gets its own virtual address space, so fixed addresses do not create a risk of address collisions.

Comment: Yes you are both right actually, I did not think about the address space. Thank you for your answers guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDB disables ASLR by default.  If you `set disable-randomization off`, then a PIE executable (Position Indepdent) will load at a randomized address even when you `run` it from inside GDB.

See [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427) for more about PIE.

Position-*dependent* executables are *always* loaded at the same address, and only their stack address can be randomized.  The code+data can hard-code addresses as 32-bit absolute, and they don't contain relocation info for every place where that was done.  (e.g. like `mov $string, %edi` ; `call puts`).

Look at gcc's code-gen for Hello World with/without `-fPIE` [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0D%0Aint+main()%7B%0D%0A++++printf(%22Hello+World!!%5Cn%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:38.86283704572098,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-fPIE',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:47.67631078175198,l:'4',m:33.74870197300104,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),l:'4',m:66.25129802699897,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:61.13716295427902,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

```
.LC0:
    .string "Hello World!"
main:
    lea     rdi, .LC0[rip]     # RIP-relative with -fPIE
    sub     rsp, 8
    call    puts@PLT
    xor     eax, eax
    add     rsp, 8
    ret
```

but with `-fno-PIE` (the default on Godbolt, often not the default on modern Linux distros), you get `mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0`, a 32-bit absolute address.

(The rest of the code is the same, except it emits `call puts` and lets the linker convert that to `call puts@PLT`.  Use `-fno-plt` to inline an indirect `call` through the GOT address.)